# Which Java Collection is best for this scenario

Tags: java

In my application I have small tables(files) with unique keys (most of those have two or more feilds - composed keys). I would like to create a class for each of those small tables and load the data in to a java collection. This object will read the file and load the data in to a a java collection. I would then like to fetch the data from this collection by the key values so that I can have access to all fields. My question is which collection I should use or say which collection supports multiple keys? A link to an examole will be great. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean by multiple keys. Could you provide an example?

Comment: For example a data record contains ten fields but the first two fields, say Fld1 and Fld2 make that record unique. So to store and pull the data record from java collection those two key fields should match. Like query where xyz.FLD1 = "AA" and xyz.FLD2 = "123".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not completely sure what you mean by multiple keys.  A class per 'table' that you can store in  a collection and fetch with a key/value pair says HashMap to me.

Comment: user181533 - That is true too. A HashMap per table where key is combination of two fields. So this will work like this: Query on table to get all rows (objects) and build a querylist and then a List from QueryList. Then iterate on List to ceate a HashMap, correct? So this all can be done in contructor. Then create a method which takes arguments for key and return the table object from HasMap.  Since I am new to this so please correct me if my understanding is not correct. Thanks,

Comment: user181533 I am going with your answer and off course whosoever has suggested HashMap but would like you confirm if my approach to create and retrieve the HashMap is correct.  Thanks  @Louis

Answer (score 4):

Assuming I've read your question correctly (there's some ambiguity about "multiple keys") what you want is to define a class for the key itself that contains the multiple fields and implements `equals()` and `hashCode()` in such a way that the objects can be used as `HashMap` keys.

Here's a very simple skeleton implementation (not tested, some error handling omitted):

```
public class MyKey
{
    private String  part1 = null;
    private Integer part2 = null;
    public MyKey(String part1, int part2)
    {
        this.part1 = part1;
        this.part2 = part2;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o == null || !(o instanceof MyKey)) return false;
        return this.part1.equals(((MyKey)o).part1) && this.part2.equals(((MyKey)o).part2);
    }

    @Override 
    public int hashCode()
    {
        return this.part1.hashCode() + this.part2.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks JIm. What I was thinking to create a List of Object where entire table is loaded in to the list. Then create a getter methode which takes FLD1 and FLD2 as arguments and return the Object where FLD1 and FLD2 match on the Object in teh List. Just iterator or For loop over the list. But I am not sure if this is teh right way to do.

Comment: Jim, If i create a class which runs a query on a file and load the data (all objects) into a list. The class will have a method which takes FLD1 and FLD2 as argument and return the matched entity (object). So this way whenever an instance of that class is created it will load the data into a list. I keep thinking about this List beacuse I am bit familiar with that. Is that the right way to do or shoudl take another approach. I am jsut new to Java  that is why want to make sure. Thanks. Peter @JimGarrison

Answer (score 1):

A Hashtable would probably work best to store the contents of each table. A Hashtable basically allows you to add any number of objects you want, and each one has a unique key.

My suggestion would be to do the following for each table file. In my example, I am assuming that you read each line of your table file into an object called Entry...

```
// Create a new Hashtable, where the contents will be a String (the unique key) and an "Entry" object for the table row of data
Hashtable<String,Entry> entriesTable = new Hashtable<String,Entry>();

for (each line in your table file){
  // Generate the unique value for this row. If there are multiple columns that make up the key,
  // just join them together into a single String
  String key = uniqueColumn1 + uniqueColumn2 + ...;

  // Create an object for your row, if you dont have one already.
  Entry row = new Entry(line);

  // Add the entry to the Hashtable
  entriesTable.put(key,row);
  }
```

When you want to get a row from the table, you ask for it by its unique value...

```
Entry entry = entriesTable.get(uniqueColumn1 + uniqueColumn2 + ...);
```

You can add as many objects as you like, provided each have a unique key. The Hashtable supports adding and removing of values, etc, so its pretty easy to work with.

You can also convert a Hashtable into an array if you want, and you can obtain an Enumerator for walking over each entry if you need to get the full contents of the Hashtable.

Comment: Thanks, will go with that. Basically I will be reading my table from mainframe through query, build a query list and then from querylist create Hashtable for each entity. Thanks again!

Comment: Why would you possibly use a `Hashtable` instead of a `HashMap` and `Iterator`?  This isn't Java 1.2.